# pulse audio sink, what are they?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

Call it cultivating curiosity  but what do the sinks stand for exactly, when i run

```
pactl list sinks | egrep  'Sink|State|Mute|Volume'
```

I get the output below, what I'm not understanding is sink #0 is running, but i have no sound running, and no audio inputs are plugged into my machine. if i had to guess I'd say sink #0 was my internal card and sink #1 was any outputs but that's a wild guess.

```
Sink #0
State: RUNNING
Mute: no
Volume: front-left: 32768 /  50% / -18.06 dB,   front-right: 32768 /  50% / -18.06 dB
Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB

Sink #1
State: IDLE
Mute: no
Volume: front-left: 32768 /  50%,   front-right: 32768 /  50%
Base Volume: 65536 / 100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you remove the `egrep` part or add `Name|Description` to it. this will shed some light. e.g. for my `Sink #0` I get

```
Name: alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo
Description: Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series] Digital Stereo (HDMI)
```

Comment: psh hahaha god love you man for not overlooking the obvious